# Migrating from ros indigo to ros kinetic, CMake can't finish the run

Tags: ros, c++, orocos, ros-kinetic, c++11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently trying to compile a project from Ubuntu 14.04 in 16.04 and have had to fix quite a few problems. This probem seems to be related to orocos for ros, but I’m unable to find the origin of the problem, so I have mostly made random searches with key words I thought to be relevant.

I am posting here because I thing the problem may be related to ros, maybe some compatibiliy error between ros indigo and ros kinetic?

For this project I am using these orocos packages for ros: rtt_ros_integration, rtt_common_msgs, rtt_ros_comm and rtt-roscomm and it is constructed with catkin

Does anyone understand what the problem is?
I am not the one that made this CMake project and I haven't been able to locate the origin of the problem, so I can’t provide more info.

Here is the error generated by cmake:

```
-- Checking for one of the modules 'rtt_rosgraph_msgs-gnulinux'
-- [UseOrocos] Found orocos package 'rtt_rosgraph_msgs'.
-- Checking for one of the modules 'rtt_geometry_msgs-gnulinux'
-- [UseOrocos] Found orocos package 'rtt_geometry_msgs'.
-- - Detected OROCOS_TARGET environment variable. Using: gnulinux
-- Found orocos-rtt 2.9.0 for the gnulinux target. Available transports: corba mqueue
-- - Found requested orocos-rtt components: rtt-marshalling rtt-scripting rtt-scripting rtt-marshalling rtt-transport-mqueue rtt-transport-corba
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- ros_generate_rtt_typekit: Could not find any .msg files in the lc_control package.
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- [UseOrocos] Building plugin library rtt_lc_control_rosservice_proxies CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/cmake/orocos-rtt/UseOROCOS-RTT.cmake:761 (target_link_libraries):   Target "lc_control_generate_messages_eus" of type UTILITY may not be linked   into another target.  One may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries, or   to executables with the ENABLE_EXPORTS property set. Call Stack (most recent call first):   /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/cmake/orocos-rtt/UseOROCOS-RTT.cmake:786 (orocos_plugin)   /opt/ros/kinetic/share/rtt_roscomm/src/templates/service/CMakeLists.txt:93 (orocos_service)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/cmake/orocos-rtt/UseOROCOS-RTT.cmake:761 (target_link_libraries):   Target "lc_control_generate_messages_nodejs" of type UTILITY may not be   linked into another target.  One may link only to STATIC or SHARED   libraries, or to executables with the ENABLE_EXPORTS property set. Call Stack (most recent call first):   /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/cmake/orocos-rtt/UseOROCOS-RTT.cmake:786 (orocos_plugin)   /opt/ros/kinetic/share/rtt_roscomm/src/templates/service/CMakeLists.txt:93 (orocos_service)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/rtt_roscomm/src/templates/service/CMakeLists.txt:94 (target_link_libraries):   Target "lc_control_generate_messages_eus" of type UTILITY may not be linked   into another target.  One may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries, or   to executables with the ENABLE_EXPORTS property set.


CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/rtt_roscomm/src/templates/service/CMakeLists.txt:94 (target_link_libraries):   Target "lc_control_generate_messages_nodejs" of type UTILITY may not be   linked into another target.  One may link only to STATIC or SHARED   libraries, or to executables with the ENABLE_EXPORTS property set.


-- [UseOrocos] Generating package version 0.0.0 from rtt_lc_control_VERSION (package.xml).
-- [UseOrocos] Generating pkg-config file for package in catkin devel space.
-- [UseOrocos] Exporting targets rtt_lc_control_rosservice_proxies;roscpp_generate_messages_cpp;roscpp_generate_messages_eus;roscpp_generate_messages_lisp;roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs;roscpp_generate_messages_py;rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp;rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus;rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp;rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs;rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py;std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp;std_msgs_generate_messages_eus;std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp;std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs;std_msgs_generate_messages_py.
-- [UseOrocos] Exporting libraries rtt_lc_control_rosservice_proxies;lc_control_generate_messages_eus;lc_control_generate_messages_nodejs;Orchestrator;BaseRamper;BaseSampler;MobilePID;MecanumIK;MecanumIK_rosHwi;MecanumIK_realHwi;MecanumFK;MecanumFK_realHwi;MecanumFK_rosHwi;MobileStatus_rosHwi;TrayPID;ScrewIK;ScrewIK_rosHwi;ScrewIK_realHwi;ScrewFK;ScrewFK_rosHwi;ScrewFK_realHwi;TrayStatus_rosHwi;ArmSampler;ArmIK;ArmIK_rosHwi;ArmIK_realHwi;ArmFK_realHwi;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librtt_rostopic-gnulinux.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_roscomm/plugins/librtt_rostopic_service-gnulinux.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_roscomm/plugins/librtt_rosservice_registry-gnulinux.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_roscomm/plugins/librtt_rosservice-gnulinux.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/liborocos-rtt-gnulinux.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libroscpp.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_signals.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librosconsole.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librosconsole_backend_interface.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cxx.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librostime.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libcpp_common.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconsole_bridge.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_std_msgs/plugins/librtt-ros-primitives-transport-gnulinux.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_std_msgs/types/librtt-std_msgs-typekit-gnulinux.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_std_msgs/types/librtt-std_msgs-ros-transport-gnulinux.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_rosgraph_msgs/types/librtt-rosgraph_msgs-typekit-gnulinux.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_rosgraph_msgs/types/librtt-rosgraph_msgs-ros-transport-gnulinux.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_geometry_msgs/types/librtt-geometry_msgs-typekit-gnulinux.so;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_geometry_msgs/types/librtt-geometry_msgs-ros-transport-gnulinux.so.
-- [UseOrocos] Exporting include directories /opt/ros/kinetic/include/orocos;/opt/ros/kinetic/include;/usr/include;/opt/ros/kinetic/share/xmlrpcpp/cmake/../../../include/xmlrpcpp.
-- [UseOrocos] Exporting library directories /home/onilsson/DevRoot/src/catkin_ws/install/lib/orocos/gnulinux/lc_control;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_roscomm/plugins;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_std_msgs/plugins;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_std_msgs/types;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_rosgraph_msgs/types;/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_geometry_msgs/types.
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rtt_actionlib_examples'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rtt_ros_examples/rtt_actionlib_examples)
-- - Detected OROCOS_TARGET environment variable. Using: gnulinux
-- Orocos-RTT found in /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/cmake/orocos-rtt/orocos-rtt-gnulinux-libraries.cmake
-- Found orocos-rtt 2.9.0 for the gnulinux target. Available transports: corba mqueue
-- - Found requested orocos-rtt components: rtt-marshalling rtt-scripting
-- [UseOrocos] Building package rtt_actionlib_examples with catkin develspace support.
-- [UseOrocos] Using Orocos RTT in rtt_actionlib_examples
-- Checking for one of the modules 'ocl-gnulinux'
-- [UseOrocos] Found orocos package 'ocl'.
-- Checking for one of the modules 'rtt_ros-gnulinux'
-- [UseOrocos] Found orocos package 'rtt_ros'.
-- Checking for one of the modules 'rtt_rosclock-gnulinux'
-- [UseOrocos] Found orocos package 'rtt_rosclock'.
-- Checking for one of the modules 'rtt_roscomm-gnulinux'
-- [UseOrocos] Found orocos package 'rtt_roscomm'.
-- Checking for one of the modules 'rtt_actionlib-gnulinux'
-- [UseOrocos] Found orocos package 'rtt_actionlib'.
-- Checking for one of the modules 'rtt_actionlib_msgs-gnulinux'
-- [UseOrocos] Found orocos package 'rtt_actionlib_msgs'.
-- Checking for one of the modules 'roscpp-gnulinux'
-- Checking for one of the modules 'actionlib-gnulinux'
-- Checking for one of the modules 'actionlib_msgs-gnulinux'
-- Checking for one of the modules 'message_generation-gnulinux'
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Generating .msg files for action rtt_actionlib_examples/SomeAction /home/onilsson/DevRoot/src/catkin_ws/src/rtt_ros_examples/rtt_actionlib_examples/action/SomeAction.action Generating for action SomeAction
-- rtt_actionlib_examples: 7 messages, 0 services
-- - Detected OROCOS_TARGET environment variable. Using: gnulinux
-- Found orocos-rtt 2.9.0 for the gnulinux target. Available transports: corba mqueue
-- - Found requested orocos-rtt components: rtt-marshalling rtt-scripting rtt-scripting rtt-marshalling rtt-transport-mqueue rtt-transport-corba
-- [UseOrocos] Building typekit library rtt-rtt_actionlib_examples-typekit
-- [UseOrocos] Building typekit library rtt-rtt_actionlib_examples-ros-transport
-- Checking for one of the modules 'ocl-deployment-gnulinux;ocl-deployment'
-- [UseOrocos] Found orocos package 'ocl-deployment'.
-- Checking for one of the modules 'ocl-taskbrowser-gnulinux;ocl-taskbrowser'
-- [UseOrocos] Found orocos package 'ocl-taskbrowser'.
-- [UseOrocos] Building executable test_server
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/onilsson/DevRoot/src/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "/home/onilsson/DevRoot/src/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log". Invoking "cmake" failed
```

------------------------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------------------

After a suggestion from gvdhoorn, I made a post on the orocos issue tracker [here](https://github.com/orocos/rtt_ros_integration/issues/105)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295911/migrating-from-ros-indigo-to-ros-kinetic,-cmake-can%27t-finish-the-run./) by [onilsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/36188/onilsson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-02**:
+100 for copy-pasting the console text (instead of screenshotting it), but could you please do it again? Use the `Preformatted Text` button this time though (the one with `101010` on it) instead of the block quote. It's rather unreadable like this.

**Comment by [onilsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/36188/onilsson/) on 2018-07-02**:
Thank's for your input gvdhoorn, I thought it would be better with the block quote, but now it's changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> -- [UseOrocos] Building plugin library rtt_lc_control_rosservice_proxies CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/cmake/orocos-rtt/UseOROCOS-RTT.cmake:761 (target_link_libraries):   Target "lc_control_generate_messages_eus" of type UTILITY may not be linked   into another target.  One may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries, or   to executables with the ENABLE_EXPORTS property set. Call Stack (most recent call first):   /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/cmake/orocos-rtt/UseOROCOS-RTT.cmake:786 (orocos_plugin)   /opt/ros/kinetic/share/rtt_roscomm/src/templates/service/CMakeLists.txt:93 (orocos_service)
> ```

From this error I would say this is a problem with the `orocos_rtt` / `rtt_roscomm` packages, or at least with one of the build scripts they provide (`orocos-rtt/UseOROCOS-RTT.cmake`).

Reporting this as an issue on the appropriate OROCOS issue tracker seems like the best course of action.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [onilsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/36188/onilsson/) on 2018-07-02**:
Ok, thank you for your swift answer. I will post on the issue tracker too then.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-02**:
If you do post on their tracker(s), please post back a link to the issue(s) here to keep things connected.

**Comment by [onilsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/36188/onilsson/) on 2018-07-02**:
Ok, I will do that as soon as I find the issue tracker

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-02**:
Probably one of the repositories under [github.com/orocos](https://github.com/orocos) ([rtt_ros_integration](https://github.com/orocos/rtt_ros_integration)?)

**Comment by [onilsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/36188/onilsson/) on 2018-07-02**:
Thanks! I think I posted it on the wrong page, now it's under [rtt_ros_integration](https://github.com/orocos/rtt_ros_integration/issues/105)